# Challenge with Cookie authentication in MVC and Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, cookies, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I am working on an enterprise application where I have 4 different Web API services for different clients. The total platform is governed by forms authentication. I came across a helpful link in doing this and implemented the solution as per the link https://wesleycabus.be/2014/06/adding-an-mvc-layer-on-top-of-a-web-api-backend/ .

I extended the above sample and wrote a new authentication service and issued the cookie and the token from the same, I have also observed that I am able to use the token from the authentication service to the service that is given in the demo, provided I gave the same machine key. But when ever I try to access a newly created service I am unable to access though all settings are intact.

I found this behavior very weird and compared the two projects. the only difference I see is the version of few nuget packages, other than that I don't see any configuration on code difference. Any help what might be the issues I am facing here. Thanks in advance.

**The only difference i see is for the service that is not working the response headers are like this**

Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:81
Content-Type:application/xml; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 08 Jan 2016 18:12:44 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate:Bearer
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcTWFjQm9vayBEYXRhXEFkaXR5YVxFQ0RQU291cmNlQ29kZVxPQlJGXFRlYW1QT0NzXEF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uXE12Y092ZXJXZWJBcGlcQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25TZXJ2aWNlXGFwaVx2YWx1ZXM=?=

**For the service that works the response headers are**

Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:195
Content-Type:application/xml; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 08 Jan 2016 18:14:32 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcTWFjQm9vayBEYXRhXEFkaXR5YVxFQ0RQU291cmNlQ29kZVxPQlJGXFRlYW1QT0NzXEF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uXE12Y092ZXJXZWJBcGlcTXlTZXJ2aWNlXGFwaVx2YWx1ZXM=?=
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive

wonder what the bearer stands for in the response header.

Note: I am able to access the newly created services by passing the token in authentication header, I am unable to access it when I try doing it using a cookie.

Comment: Is the app and services hosted under the same domain? You may have to implement CORS. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Yes..in fact i am unable to authenticate with the new service even when i am debugging in Visual Studio also.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue. There was version mis-match issue in the Microsoft.Owin.Security dll between the two services. Once I made sure the version is same